# Redux Toolkit, when to use createListenerMiddleware over createAsyncThunk

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

Suppose I have a Redux slice like this

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authInfo',
    initialState: {value: ""},
    reducers: {
      setAuthState: (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.value = action.payload;
      },
    }
})
```

and I want to keep the authState also on the Encrypted Storage via an async call.

Until now I always thought that the go-to choice for asyncronous operations was `createAsyncThunk`, defining something like this

```
export const storeAuthState = createAsyncThunk(
  'authInfo/storeAuthState',
  async (authState: any) => {
    await EncryptedStorage.setItem('auth_state', JSON.stringify(authState));
    return authState;
  },
);
...
const authSlice = createSlice({
...
    reducers: {
    ...
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(storeAuthState.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload;
        })
    ...
```

and by dispatching `storeAuthState` whenever I update it.

However I just discovered the existence of `createListenerMiddleware` with which I can achieve the same goal in this way:

```
export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: setAuthState,
    effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
        await EncryptedStorage.setItem('auth_state', JSON.stringify(action.payload))
    }
})
```

To me there is no much difference in the two approaches, I understand that the order in which the Redux Store and the Encrypted Storage are updated is different, but in the end the result is the same.

Probably the second solution looks cleaner, so I was wondering what are some real (the example on rtk website for createListenerMiddleware is really vague) use cases that these two methods aim at resolving and when I should adopt one solution over the other?

Answer (score 1):

They're different tools, for different purposes.

A thunk is "imperative".  It's "go do *this* thing, right now".

A listener is "reactive". It's "when *this* thing happens, run *that* code in response".

As an example of this: note that in your thunk example, the async logic happens first, then the action is dispatched, then the reducer updates.

With the listener, the action is dispatched and the reducer updates, *then* the listener runs and does more work.

More specifically, `createAsyncThunk` is "go do some async work right now, and dispatch actions before and after the async logic".  `createListenerMiddleware` is "whenever this action is dispatched, go do this other additional work".

Metaphorically, it's like a hammer and a screwdriver.  They're both tools you would use for building a house, but you use them at different times for different kinds of tasks as part of the overall building effort.

Also see the "Side Effects Approaches" page in the Redux docs:

- https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches

Comment: As I said, I understand that the order in which operations take place is different, but changing the order of the operands does not change the result. In this particular case (or in a logout where you have to both clean the store and do some cleanup via async logic) I can't understand which is the correct tool to use.

Comment: As you saw, in this particular case you _can_ accomplish the goal (persist the data) with either of them. It's a question of whether you want to do that _imperatively_ or _reactively_.  Personally, I'd lean towards using the listener middleware myself, but in this case it's mostly up to you.